# Yii2 GridView attribute format defined by different attribute value

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, format

I would like to define the format of an attribute in `GridView` based on a db field value. I was trying for example like this:

```
'format' => function ($model) {return $model->format;}, // it should return 'boolean'
```

but I have tried many other ways also, but it's not working. I'm getting:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

If I'm simply returning `format` as an attribute, it's working without any issues. It seems that it's not accepting it in the `format` section.
Is it possible anyways what I'm trying to achieve? Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Closure`s for `format` are not supported. You may use `raw` format and do formatting in `Closure` for `value`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $format = 'as' . ucfirst($model->format);
        return Yii::$app->formatter->$format($model->name);
    },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Yii2 Formatter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter)

Example:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
     'id' => 'grid-list',
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     [
         'attribute' => 'format_date',
          // 'format' => 'raw',
         'value' => function ($model) {
              // Here use \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate();
              // Ex: return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->format_date);
              return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->format_date);
         },
     ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: looks good: `'value' => function ($model) {return \Yii::$app->formatter->{$model->format}($model->value);},` Many thanks for both of you! It's a little bit hard to decide which one of you has earned the points, because **rob006** has taken the time to fix my question, and he is explaining it better, however, technically your answer is also correct.